# automatic currency on textbox in asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, textbox, decimal, currency

what i want to happen is to have 12,345.00 rather than 12,345.

here is my code:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtProductPrice" runat="server" onkeyup = "javascript:this.value=Comma(this.value);" class="form-control" MaxLength ="6"></asp:TextBox>
```

and the javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

function Comma(Num) {
    Num += '';
    Num = Num.replace(',', ''); Num = Num.replace(',', ''); Num = Num.replace(',', '');
    Num = Num.replace(',', ''); Num = Num.replace(',', ''); Num = Num.replace(',', '');
    x = Num.split('.');
    x1 = x[0];
    x2 = x.length > 1 ? '.' + x[1] : '';
    var rgx = /(\d+)(\d{3})/;
    while (rgx.test(x1))
        x1 = x1.replace(rgx, '$1' + ',' + '$2');
    return x1 + x2;
}

</script>
```

any tricks? thank you

Comment: try using Function retundecimal(num){ return numtoFixed(2);}

Comment: where do i put it? @Mysterio11

Answer (score 0):

there is a jquery plugin called "jquery.formatCurrency" (https://code.google.com/archive/p/jquery-formatcurrency/). It could meet your requirements.

Sebastian